# Remove duplicate values in a column after join in drupal 7

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, database

I am using this db_select query.

```
$query = db_select('taxonomy_index', 't1');
    $query->distinct();
    $query->join('node', 't2', 't1.nid = t2.nid');
    $query->join('taxonomy_term_data', 't3', 't3.tid = t1.tid');
    $query->fields('t1', array('tid'));
    $query->fields('t3', array('name'));
    $query->fields('t1', array('nid'));
    $query->groupBy('t1.nid');
    $query->condition('t2.type', 'article', '=');
    $query->condition('t3.vid', '2', '=');
    $query->orderBy('t2.created', 'DESC');
    $query->range(0, 20);
    $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll(); 
    print_r($result);
```

After running this query 
my output is

```
tid  name   nid
1    apple   200
5    orange  165
9    grapes  130
5    orange  106
```

My expecting output is

```
 tid  name   nid
    1    apple   200
    5    orange  165
    9    grapes  130
```

No need to repeat duplicate rows like  5 orange 106 again. How this can be possible?

Comment: I think you want to group by t3.name, not t1.nid.

Comment: I already tried that... it is not satisfying $query->orderBy('t2.created', 'DESC'); this condition

Comment: OrderBy is not a condition, so it's not clear what you mean by this.

Comment: it is not working .......am getting same output...

Comment: I don't see how that is possible.

Comment: u can try.... it will not work... if it work means why should i want to post it here

Comment: I mean I don't see how it is possible that after making the change I suggested, you could end up with the same results. If the results are the same, it means you have not made the change I suggested. With the change I suggested, the results may not be what you want, but the results will definitely not be the same as the original code.

Comment: not working....

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with the result you are getting and avoid the duplicates using below codes.

```
 $used_tids = array();
 foreach ($result as $row) {
        if (!in_array($row->tid, $used_tids)) {
          $new_result[] = $row;
          $used_tids[] = $row->tid;
        }
      }
      // new filtered results after avoiding duplicates
      $results = $new_result;
```

Comment: @Polite User Have you tried this? If it is not working please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here there is no use of joining with node table. If you are getting the taxonomy grouped by tag name and to get the node count, then it make sense to JOIN the node table. Otherwise directly query the taxonomy table.

Ref: https://www.drupal.org/node/494026#comment-4126908

```
$vid = 3; //vocabulary id
$num_term = 20; //limit maximum terms

$query = "SELECT tid, name, count
FROM (
SELECT td.tid AS tid, name, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM {term_data} AS td
JOIN {term_node }AS tn ON td.tid = tn.tid
JOIN {node} AS n ON n.nid = tn.nid AND n.vid = tn.vid
WHERE td.vid = ". $vid ." AND n.status = 1
GROUP BY td.tid
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT ". $num_term . "
) AS t
ORDER BY name ASC";

$result = db_query($query);
while ($term = db_fetch_object($result)) {
if ($term->count > 0) {
  $items[]= l($term->name, "taxonomy/term/$term->tid") . ' (' . $term->count . ')';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Drupal 8 then you can overwrite result with your desired result using hook_views_pre_render

```
    function HOOK_views_pre_render(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view) {    

      if ($view->id() == 'view_machine_name' && $view->current_display == 'display_id') { // page_1

        foreach ($view->result as $key => $value) {

                  //do your business logic here
              }

      }

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The OP didn't say they are using the Views module. The question is about code querying the database. I would not suggest using a view to a user who is trying to programmatically query the database.